# PowerShell: How to set a policy for a list of APIs with multiple xml files?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-api-management

I have a script that sets policies for Azure APIs, and I have a list of operations I'm retrieving from a yaml file. Each operation has a specific policy that needs to be assigned to that operation, and those are separate xml files.

operations:
These are sitting in a yml file.

```
post-cloud-knox
post-cloud-cn
get-cloud-pa
get-cloud-cn
```

Then I have the policies defined in my directory as:

```
post-cloud-knox.xml
post-cloud-cn.xml
get-cloud-pa.xml
get-cloud-cn.xml
```

So, how do I grab the operations text in the **yml** file and assign these policies to each, since their names match.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: this is just badly written coder23.

Answer (score 0):

Set-Execution Policy is the command that can help you out here.
Please refer to these examples for setting the execution Policy.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7